# biblatex-chicago problem after update

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago, update

After updating my TeXLive 2020 distribution today, biblatex-chicago has stopped working for me.

The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test2020,
  title = {Test title},
  author = {Author},
  date = {2020},
  publisher = {test},
  location = {test},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{test2020}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \blx@defformat@i was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.2523 \DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{\par
                                           \nobreak \vskip \bibitemsep #1}
```

The culprit must be in one of these packages, I think, but I'm unable to detect which one:

```
[ 5/24, 00:31/15:37] update: biber.x86_64-darwin [27659k] (53064 -> 56144) ... done
[ 6/24, 02:37/05:09] update: biber [1165k] (53064 -> 56144) ... done
[ 7/24, 02:42/05:07] update: biblatex [7408k] (53063 -> 56143) ... done
[ 8/24, 02:54/04:26] update: biblatex-ext [617k] (56081 -> 56150) ... done
[ 9/24, 02:57/04:26] update: biblatex-jura2 [367k] (53243 -> 56133) ... done
```

I have this problem (since today's update) on a Mac and a Linux machine. (I haven't updated another Linux machine which still compiles alright this MWE.)

Any ideas?

Comment: That should probably be considered a `biblatex` bug. I shall be investigating. Though I'm not sure if I can get something done before tomorrow. The problematic commit is probably https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/089ce33f1e3cbde9433fda6e8ab4c82e96018b80.

Comment: You're right! Reverting the commit for lines 4187--4195 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

`biblatex` v3.15a with the fix for this bug was released on 2020-08-23 and made it to CTAN and into TeX live (you want at least revision `56165`) on the same night.

Update your system if you are still experiencing this bug.

---

This is a bug in `biblatex` 3.15 (it is tracked at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1037 and was introduced in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/089ce33f1e3cbde9433fda6e8ab4c82e96018b80 where an argument that was implicit before was made explicit and only short because the macro in question uses `\def` and not `\long\def`).

I shall have a look at the best solution. In the meantime here is a **temporary and quick workaround**. The workaround uses the new file loading hooks (so that feature comes in handy). You'll need to add the hook code for every `.bbx` or `.cbx` file you load that makes use of long field formats.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter
\csdef{blx@filehook@preload@chicago-notes.cbx}{%
\def\blx@defformat@i##1##2##3[##4]##5{%
  \notblank{##3}
    {\blx@resetformat{##2}{##5}}
    {}%
  \def\blx@defformat@a{##2}%
  \def\blx@defformat@b{##4}%
  \blx@xsanitizeafter{\def\blx@defformat@c}{##5}%
  \afterassignment\blx@defformat@ii
  ##1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't really grasp the gist of your solution, however. For the moment I have changed lines 4187--4195  of `biblatex.sty` to remove argument `#6`.

Comment: @NVaughan The main problem is that the argument `#6` is now grabbed explicitly by `\blx@defformat@i`and not as before implicitly by another helper macro. Due to the definition of `\blx@defformat@i` that argument is short, i.e. can't contain `\par`. So everything with `\par` in the argument of `\DeclareFieldFormat` now breaks. One solution is to make `\blx@defformat@i` `\long` so that a `\par` is again fine. Another solution would be to just undo the linked commit and remove `#6`. The answer shows a way to fix `biblatex` without modification of the `.sty` file.

Comment: That's clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: @NVaughan `biblatex` 3.15a with a slightly different fix (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/cd87f977bd01c55cfdd10835e592a78e9e3329ec) is on its way to CTAN. If everything goes smoothly the error should be fixed with tomorrow's TeX live updates. I'll update the answer tomorrow or the day after that.

Comment: Thanks. I have just updated and works fine.