# New possible bug in biblatex-chicago: how to make new error message go away

Tags: biblatex-chicago, bugs

Ever since updating all packages on TeX Live Utility (on Mac OS) yesterday, including `biblatex-chicago`, I have been getting this non-critical error message/warning every time I run `xelatex` on a file using `biblatex-chicago`:

```
Runaway argument?
{
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx
:6629: Paragraph ended before \blx@defformat@i was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6629 \DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{\par
                                           \nobreak \vskip \bibitemsep #1}
? 
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx
:6629: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
l.6629 ...ation}{\par\nobreak \vskip \bibitemsep #
                                                  1}
? 

/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-chicago/chicago-notes.cbx
:6629: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Is this due to a bug? And if so, is there some way to fix it?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/559645/35864. The bug fix `biblatex` 3.15a was sent to CTAN yesterday and was picked up by TeX live tonight. It should already be available on the fast mirrors and should become more widespread until tomorrow. Try if you can update your system to get a new `biblatex`.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, somehow that didn't come up in my search! Thank you for the quick fix -- and quick reply.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of the linked question to avoid duplication of information in different places.